# How can I create a reduced data frame which sums a numeric variable based on another variable?

Tags: r

As an example if I have the table:

```
ID   X     Year
1    2.5   1990
2    3.5   1991
3    4.0   1990
4    4.5   1991
```

How can I create a new reduced table that sums up X by Year

```
Year    X
1990    6.5
1991    8.0
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you even tried anything? Or at least using Google? Or reading some tutorials? This is a very basic question, I can think of atleast of 3 different ways of doing it in base R and another 4-5 ways with external packages. If you don't know how to use the 'Google', let me help you. Try typing, for example, "aggregate data r" in the search window

Comment: I did try googling the subject in my query but did not get far, but I guess my problem was that I did not even know what keywords to search for in google. I think "aggregate" will help me make progress through google search. I also tried dcast from reshape2 based on some example that was probably trying to do something different and that did not work. But thanks for putting me on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

Use data.table for this type of work:

Step0: data creation

```
df <- data.frame(x=((5:9)/2)[-2],year=rep(1990:1991,2))
```

Step1: Convert data.frame to data.table:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
```

Step2: Perform the sum by year:

```
df[,sum(x),by=year]
```

For more details read about data.table. They have extensive documentation.

Comment: Thanks! I tried both aggregate with data frame and the summing on data table as suggested by you and both worked. The data set I am working with is very large and I noticed that the latter approach seemed to work significantly faster.

Comment: Ya. data.table give a significant boost on large datasets, upto 10x. Glad it worked.

Answer (score 0):

`dplyr` could be also used for large datasets

```
library(dplyr)
df%>% group_by(year) %>% summarize(X=sum(x))

#   year   X
#1 1990 6.5
#2 1991 8.0
```